# How to save foreign key to multiple tables asp.net mvc entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am making a functionality that lets admin to configure a mailing setting for users. There are multiple entities:

1. Buildings
2. Services
3. Users

In the configuration form admin can select multiple buildings, multiple services and multiple users. So all the selected users will get mails for all the buildings and services that were selected. In the view I have 3 multiselect lists for buildings, services and users.

There can also be multiple settings.

Now I have the following entities:

```
public class MailingConfigSetting
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SettingId { get; set; }
    public string SettingName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailingConfigUser> MailingConfigUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailingConfigBuilding> MailingConfigBuildings { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MailingConfigService> MailingConfigServices { get; set; }
}
public class MailingConfigUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class MailingConfigBuilding
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BuildingId { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
}

public class MailingConfigService
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(MailingConfigVM mailingConfigVM)
    {
        if (!SessionControlService.CheckIsLoginStillTrue(_loginsService, HttpContext))
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        var curUser = _userService.GetUserByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        if (!User.IsInAnyRoles("Admin"))
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            using (var domain = new Facility.Data.FacilityEntities())
            {
                var newSetting = new Facility.Model.MailingConfigSetting
                {
                    SettingName = "testSetting"
                };
                domain.MailingConfigSettings.Add(newSetting);

                foreach (int item in mailingConfigVM.SelectedBuildings)
                {
                    var building = _buildingService.GetBuilding((int)item);

                    var newSettingBuilding = new Facility.Model.MailingConfigBuilding
                    {
                        BuildingId = building.Id,
                        BuildingName = building.Name,

                    };
                    domain.MailingConfigBuildings.Add(newSettingBuilding);
                }

                foreach (int item in mailingConfigVM.SelectedServices)
                {
                    var service = _serviceService.GetService(item);
                    var newSettingService = new Facility.Model.MailingConfigService
                    {
                        ServiceId = service.Id,
                        ServiceName = service.Name
                    };
                    domain.MailingConfigServices.Add(newSettingService);
                }

                foreach (int item in mailingConfigVM.SelectedUsers)
                {
                    var user = _userService.GetUser(item);
                    var newSettingUser = new Facility.Model.MailingConfigUser
                    {
                        UserId = user.Id,
                        UserName = user.UserName
                    };
                    domain.MailingConfigUsers.Add(newSettingUser);
                }

                //domain.MailingConfigBuildings.Add(newSettingBuilding);
                domain.SaveChanges();

            }
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Create", "MailingConfig");
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class MailingConfigVM
{
    [Display(Name = "Buildings")]
    //public IEnumerable<Building> allBuildings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allBuildings { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Services")]
    //public IEnumerable<Facility.Model.Service> allServices { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allServices { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Users")]
    //public IEnumerable<User> allUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> allUsers { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedBuildings { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedServices { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedUsers { get; set; }

}
```

}

I have 4 tables:

1) buildings

2) services

3) users

4) setting

Tables for buildings, services and users should contain a key from setting table.

In the controller when I save to db I can see that the results are being inserted to all tables, but they lack foreign key from setting table.

How can I also save a key from setting table to those tables?

Comment: Rather than adding the related entities directly to their `DbSet`s, try adding them to the corresponding collection navigation property of the parent entity.

Comment: @IvanStoev How do I do that?

Comment: Instead of `domain.MailingConfigBuildings.Add(newSettingBuilding);`, do `newSetting.MailingConfigBuildings.Add(newSettingBuilding);`. Same for others. Just make sure the collections are initialized with `new List<..>` or `new HashSet<...>`